# why macros return what we are not expected

Tags: c++, macros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem with Macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351051/problem-with-macros)

Hi all

I have defined this macro:

```
#define SQ(a) (a*a)
```

and called it in this way:

```
std::cout << SQ(2+3) << '\n';
```

the output was 11. Why ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macros do only simple text manipulation, i.e. they are *very* stupid that way in that they don't see 'code', only 'text' which are then sent to to the C/C++ parser for validation.

`SQ(2+3)` becomes `(2+3*2+3)`

That's why you should use templates, which are a bit smarter, they would do what you expected: first calculate 2+3, then do 5*5.

Comment: +1 for explaining, -1 since macro are not stupid, they are just what they are: a tool that sometimes is useful, sometimes it is not.

Comment: I didn't mean that the use of macros is stupid, in fact, the very next response I gave I suggested macros.  I mean that macros don't do any smart processing, they are 'stupid' in the sense that they just do text processing; sometimes that might be exactly what we want to do some very smart things..

Comment: got it: macros are what they are, and the preprocessor works like that, anyway:D stupidity is when Macro thinks to be something different, and try to compare with other tools:D

Answer (score 3):

Because the expansion of `SQ` in your example gives:

```
std::cout << (2+3*2+3) << '\n';
```

A better way to define the macro would be

```
#define SQ(a) ((a)*(a))
```

which solves the precedence issue in this case.

Better still would be to use a function which avoids any issues with the passed expression being evaluated more than once.

E.g. as a template:

```
template<class T>
T SQ(T a) { return a * a; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Fix your macro to:

```
#define SQ(a) ((a)*(a))
```

Answer (score 1):

Others already have the answer.  The "fix" (if you must use macros at all) is to wrap all your params with parens, e.g.

```
#define SQ(a) ((a)*(a))
```

In most cases, you're better off using templates as this will still perform compile-time expansion for speed, but also provides language support for syntax and type checking.